# What is single/doubled pixels setting?

Tags: pc, croc-legend-of-the-gobbos

There's "single pixels"/"doubled pixels" option in "display setup" menu (the background is in-game footage; note how UI changes as well):

[image: single pixels]
[image: double pixels]

"Single pixels" looks sharper, but what is actually changed? It may appear that the game lowers rendering resolution when "doubled pixels" is selected.

Comment: Looking at letters with only straight lines, they seem unchanged (e.g the EE in SCREEN RES). But letters with curves in them seem blockier. I think the setting changes the curves to that they always use two-pixel increments instead of one-pixel increments. I have no idea why.

Comment: As a guess, it renders it in a lower resolution to emulate the aesthetic of old N64 games.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in low detail mode(DOUBLED PIXELS), you'll receive four times less of rendered pixels, while keeping same screen resolution. This, so called "term", actually arises from old times of 320x200 VGA displays, when decreasing virtual resolutions of screen to render, caused the game to have much higher FPS.

Comment: Please add source and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Hello, source is myself. ) I've been playing this game about 10 years ago. And started playing video games in 1994. Also I've participated in several PC games creation with resolutions from 640x480 up to HD.

Comment: To confirm, "doubled pixels" is four times less and not two times?

Comment: "I've participated in several PC games creation with resolutions from 640x480 up to HD." -  Are you a game developer? What are the games  you have worked on?

Comment: Hi. ) Yes "double pixels" render 320x200 frame, instead of 640x400, and so on. ) As developer and tester I've participated in Live Billiards, Seawar Battleship, and several another casual games. I'm initial sponsor of Stalker engine, but that's quite a dark story. Besides, why are You asking? :)

Comment: Makes your answer more reputable. You could add this information to your user page. X-Ray engine? What is a "sponsor" in this context?

Comment: Yep, at the moment, I sold my flat for 3d engine development debts, this engine was called X-Ray engine. ) Then two people left us, and were hired as "Stalker" developers. They abandoned this project as well, and first Stalker version was released only due to efforts of several very talented people(well being paid of course).

Comment: Just curious, are you involved in game development?

Comment: I'm not, but S.T.A.L.K.E.R. happens to be one of my favorite series.